# PHP debug_backtrace bitmask usage

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, stack-trace, bitmask

Trying to understand this entry in the php manual on [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php).

I don't understand what they mean by "this parameter is a bitmask for ...."

I have done web searches on bitmasks and my head is spinning round so I have decided I don't really want to learn the detail about it but just to know how I can supposed to add the options to that function.

Do I put in both options as in

```
debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT, DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS)
```

if I want both and one of them if I only want that one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means you combine options with the bitwise OR operator: `|`.

For example:

```
 debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT | DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
```

For more details about bitmasks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)

Answer (score 20):

Be aware that those 2 constants (DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT, DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS) are different in meaning. While DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT provides an additional object when present, DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS strips the args when present.

Since the most common use-case for these constants is to reduce memory usage, the way with least memory-consumption is:

```
debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
```

NOT

```
// false friend!
debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT | DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
```

It overrides the default of DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT and additionally ignores DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS.

Comment: Just how I wanted it explained.

Answer (score 13):

The constants will have values of 2^n in decimal, or (10)^n in binary. For example - 1, 10, 100, 1000, etc (in binary).

Say `a=001, b=010, c=100`:

You can do bitwise or on, for example, `a` and `b`. This will mean each bit will be 'turned on' if the same bit in either a or b is 'on'.

```
a | b == 011
```

This is a bitmask. The bitmask is checked for the inclusion of `a` by

```
bitmask & a != 0
```

Which is

```
011 & 001 == 001 != 0
```

However, because c is not in the bitmask:

```
bitmask & c == 011 & 100 == 0
```

So, to include both a and b in the bitmask, you use the *binary or* operator.

```
debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT | DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
```

Comment: Yes ... very clear. Accepted the previous because it came first but voted this up in appreciation. A small follow up question is whether it is possible to load the bitmask into a php variable `$x = a | b;` or not.

Comment: Yeah it is, a bitmask is merely an integer, so it can be used in the same way as any other expression.